# Row of icons in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on my personal website and in my skills section, I want to put a row of icons at the top of the container. However, when I attempt to put a `row-fluid` on top, I run into issues.

I've attached the relevant code and screenshots for reference. Any help is appreciated!

[image: w/out icons]

[image: with icons]

```
<!--SKILLS DESCRIPTION -->
<div id="skillswrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="5s" data-wow-offset="100">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <h4 style="color:white"><b>SKILLS</b></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <p><img class="img-responsive" src="Theme/assets/img/html5.png" alt="" style="zoom:60%"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 centered">
                    <p><b>Front End Programming Skills</b></p>
                    <h5>HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Bootstrap, JQuery, AngularJS, Ionic Framework, D3
                        <br>

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 centered">
                    <p><b>Scripting Language Skills</b></p>
                    <h5>Python, Ruby</h5>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 centered">
                    <p><b>Object Oriented Experience</b></p>
                    <h5>Java, C++</h5>
                    <br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-3 centered">
                    <p><b>Communication</b></p>
                    <h5>Strong writing, collaborative and interpersonal skills.</h5>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 centered">
                    <p><b>Software</b></p>
                    <h5>Exposure to: Postman, JetBrains IDEs, Eclipse, Version control w/ Git, Adobe Creative
                        Suite.</h5><br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 centered">
                    <p><b>Diverse Technical Skills</b></p>
                    <h5>Programming, agile methedologies, QA testing, content management, data analytics</h5>
                    <br>
                </div>

            </div><!--/.row -->
            <br>
        </div><!--/.container -->
    </div>
</div><!--/ #skillswrap -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either are going to have the `offset` or `push`  bootstrap classes to push the image right i.e.: adding `col-lg-offset-1` to class,

OR

Do it yourself via the `position` css attribute i.e.: `position:relative;left:10px`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/ for more info on how to use offset, push classes.